# Building Android app deletes adb executable

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, react-native, android-build

I've created a new app using `react-native init ...`. Installed the android dev tools as per the documentation and attempting to run using `react-native run-android`.

I'm getting the error

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.
>     File 'C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 1 mins 7.058 secs

I've tried this a few times (removing then reinstalling SDK .etc.) and what I noticed was that when I install the SDK and tools, `adb` is getting installed at the above location, but when a build is started/emulator is started or android studio loads the project, it disappears (deleted?).

This happens regardless of if I run `react-native run-android` or open the `[AppFolder]\android` in Android Studio (3.0.1) and run [Run > Run 'app']

I copied the platform-tools folder elsewhere, and replaced it after android studio was opened, and adb still disappears after a few seconds when android studio or emulator was running. Same if I run `react-native run android`.

***Same project works fine on OS X.*** (I had to manually `chmod +x gradlew` after cloning the project but don't think that's related.)

**Configuration**

- OS Windows 10 v1709 (Build 16299.125) - no updates pending
- react-native 0.51
- android studio 3.0.1
- gradle version *I THINK* is 2.2.3 as of below

**build.gradle file** *(I haven't changed this - generated by react-native cli)*

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    }
}
```

**right after SDK install**

[image]

**after running android studio with project open/emulator started/ react-native run-android**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try placing adb.exe somewhere else, and make sure it's in the path?
Could it be that some antivirus deletes it?

Comment: no joy.. same error. (it did not delete my adb in other location tho) gradle task :app:installDebug looks for adb in that specific location C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe.

Comment: It's AVAST!.. it's GODDAMN AVAST. .. THANKS!!! I have like 25 copies of adb in quarantine.

Comment: You are welcome :) I know that BitDefender was doing something similar, it would delete my autoconf generated test exe files.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I missed this one. Added an exclusion to Avast and it works fine. Avast silent mode must've swallowed the notification. Merry Christmas mate!

Comment: No problem, Merry Christmas to you too :)